# Error: unsupported compressor 8

Tags: error, compressor

I wanna install python on wine, but encountered the following issue,

```
$ wine msiexec /i python-2.7.14.msi 

/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.200.3/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:49: Error: unsupported compressor 8
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.200.3/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exceptions.plist'
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.200.3/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:49: Error: unsupported compressor 8
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.200.3/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/AppExceptions.bundle/Exceptions.plist'
0009:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0009:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"WhichUsersDlg" returned 1602
```

How do I solve it?

My machine's version is macOS Mojave 10.14.6.